# How to avoid stacktrace HTTP Status 500 page with MaxUploadSizeExceededException

Tags: java, spring, servlets, file-upload, spring-mvc

I have this code (like in Spring's reference):

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" 
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

When user tries to upload file over 100 kB server error page with HTTP Status 500 and stacktrace will be displayed. How to avoid this in the simplest way? I would like to redirect to form page and show my own error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it's `org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException`, just define an `error-page` in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException</exception-type>
    <location>/upload-error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Note that this only works when you don't have another `<error-page>` which covers `ServletException` or one of its superclasses. Otherwise you've to bring in some exception filter which unwraps and rethrows the root cause of `ServletException`.